# Custom style doesn't work for buttons in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a project with two themes in res/values/themes. I want to add my own button style. I create values/styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="BeatBoxButton">
        <item name="android:background">@color/dark_blue</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then I add style attribute to Button :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.beatbox.SoundViewModel"
        />
    </data>
    <Button
        style="@style/BeatBoxButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:text="@{viewModel.title}"
        android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onButtonClick()}"
        tools:text="@string/sound_item_btn_text"
    />
</layout>
```

Now I want to see my buttons with dark_blue background. But style doesn't apply. Why? And what I need to do to apply BeatBoxButton style?

P.S.: And I have res/values/colors.xml too with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>

    <color name="red">#F44336</color>
    <color name="dark_red">#C3352B</color>
    <color name="gray">#607D8B</color>
    <color name="soothing_blue">#0083BF</color>
    <color name="dark_blue">#005A8A</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change theme in AndroidManifest to "themeApp" did the trick. And we even don't need parent attribute in our custom style!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `parent` attribute in your style, in addition to this, the `background` attribute is mean to be used with a drawable (an image, a xml...) because the background of a button is more complex than just a color, what you are looking for is the `Tint` attribute.

`Tint` attribute is used to give a color tint to the given button.

```
<style name="BeatBoxButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/dark_blue</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Yes, it's true. Why dark_blue color apply not to background, but to button text?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing changes, still apply to text. Hmm, I deleted item from this style at all, and nothing changes again.

Comment: At the same time <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item> works fine

Comment: I was not right, dark_blue wasn;t applied to text, neither background nor backgroundTint aren't apply to anything at all

Comment: And only when I changed Theme in Manifest, android:background was finally apply to button background. By the way, backgroundTint works fine too